# Windows 8 bootloader replace Windows 7's?

Tags: windows-8, bootloader

I installed Windows 8 on my system which already had Windows 7 (dual boot)

My question is, did Windows 8 install its bootloader on the Windows 7 partition, and effectively replace it?

I did notice the new Windows 8 bootloader, but if I change the default OS to Windows 7, the old Windows 7 bootloader appears again, so I just wonder if it's still there somewhere and not actually replaced

Comment: Yes, there is a new bootloader installed with Windows 8.

Comment: is there a way to restore the windows 7 one?

Comment: Repair your Windows 7 installation. But then you're unable to boot Windows 8. Why do you even care? You should be able to boot both Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: I believe the bootloader depends on the entry set to be default in the BCD store, so setting the Windows 7 one may change it. If you have to edit that I find EasyBCD quite useful (and it's free for personal usage).

Comment: I am surprised you did not see the vast difference in the bootloader screen after installing W8, which would suggest it did get replaced.

Comment: see my edited post

Answer (score 1):

The windows 8 bootloader replaced the one from Windows 7 and boots now every start. When you have other operating systems installed, e.g. windows 7, windows 8 will give you the possibility to boot this system. When you choose to boot windows 7, the bootloader will be temporary edited so your computer boots windows 7. After a shutdown or restart the windows 8 bootloader will boot windows 8 boot menu again.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows
```

I've got Windows 8 and Linux installed, and while trying to install TrueCrypt, it wants the default Windows bootloader to be installed, so I was trying to restore the default Windows 8 bootloader, but now I've got the Windows 7 bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But as Nathaniel Hitchborn says. If you change the default OS while your in Windows back to windows 7 you will get the old win 7 bootloader every time.

To change the default OS:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click on System
3. On the left hand side click Advanced System Settings
4. Click on the Advance tab from the new menu
5. Under Start-up and Recovery click Settings
6. Under default operating system, switch this to Windows 7
7. Click OK, reboot and you will get the Win7 bootloader on every start-up

Comment: Would have up voted but I'm new so I can't. Thanks for punishing me because of that. I'm still learning.

Comment: Had a go. Any better?

Comment: Thank you. I'll know what to do in the future :) many thanks.

Comment: @popcornuk Are you sure this actually changes the boot loader as opposed to just makes the existing bootloader default to Windows 8 rather than Windows 8?  Changing the boot loader and picking a default startup OS are two different functions.

Answer (score 1):

The *boot manager* is indeed newer, but what it's doing is booting the Windows 8 kernel, *then* asking you what you want to boot.

You *can* make it use the old behavior though:
From within Windows 8, run `bcdedit /set bootmenupolicy legacy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the old Windows 7 bootloader, simply make windows 7 the default OS, and it will switch to the Win7 loader.